How to get Instagram username or ID with Ad Library API (or other way)
I'm using official Facebbok API for getting ads with /ads_archive endpoint.
Example request:
curl -G \
-d "search_terms='oil'" \
-d "ad_reached_countries=['US']" \
-d "fields=id,ad_creation_time,ad_creative_bodies,ad_creative_link_captions,ad_creative_link_descriptions,ad_creative_link_titles,ad_delivery_start_time,ad_delivery_stop_time,ad_snapshot_url,age_country_gender_reach_breakdown,beneficiary_payers,bylines,currency,delivery_by_region,demographic_distribution,estimated_audience_size,eu_total_reach,impressions,languages,page_id,page_name,publisher_platforms,spend,target_ages,target_gender,target_locations" \
-d "access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/ads_archive"

Response does include Facebook Page ID. It also includes publisher_platforms field containing Instagram or/and Facebook. But no Instagram ID or username.

I find it weird, because web version of Ad Library (running under private API) shows that data. Example link

How can I get Instagram username using Official Ad Library API?
I've already passed all fields from Archived Ad Schema to my request.
Scraping private API seems hard, because it seems sensitive to proxies.

The page object has a instagram_business_account field - "Instagram account linked to page during Instagram business conversion flow" (Although I am not sure if that is necessarily the one the ad was published for, you'd have to check.)

@CBroe are you talking about https://graph.facebook.com/115602234462193?fields=instagram_business_account ?
As I understand, it is only allowed if you request your own Page. But I want to get info about any Page, even those I don't have access for.

https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/api says, below that "What you can search for through the API" headline, that "All available ads will have:" page id and name, and "Where the ad appeared (Facebook, Instagram, etc.)" Doesn't say anything about getting the actual profiles on those other platforms - so it looks like Facebook has not made this info available via the API.

Yeah, but it's weird that they include Instagram username on the Web version of Ads Library, but not in API.

People also argue that it was "weird" that user information, that is publicly visible for everyone on Facebook, isn't automatically available publicly via API as well. But it still makes a difference, regarding the amount of data you will be able to gather, whether you are doing that at "human speed" by clicking around in some GUI, or doing it at "machine speed", by making API calls.
